# Backbone route matching doesn't work

Tags: javascript, url, backbone.js, backbone-routing

I have got three routes like this:

```
var appRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "index",
        "questionnaire/info/id/:id": "questionnaireInfo",
        "questions/edit/*params": "questionEdit"
    },
    questionnaireInfo: function(id) {
        $('#app-body').load('/dashboard/questionnaire/info/id/' + id);
    },
    questionEdit: function(questionnaireId) {
        console.log(questionnaireId, params);
    },
    index: function() {
        console.log('index');
    }
});
```

And i initialize them like this:

```
var appRouting = new appRouter;
Backbone.history.start({
    pushState: true,
    silent: false,
    root: '/dashboard/'
});
```

On first page load the route matches, it even console.log the proper messages. But i have got a link element like this:

```
<a href="/dashboard">Home Page</a>
```

It doesn't match the `""` route. And this href element doesn't match the `"questionnaire/info/id/:id"` route:

```
<a href="/dashboard/questionnaire/info/id/1">Load</a>
```

How can i make this working? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're missing the '/' between '/dashboard' and each route

Comment: I don't understand your answer. I already defined it as root. Why should i prepend it too all routes.

Comment: I mean, your rule is "questions/edit/*params", but the actual path is "/questions/edit/*params" (note the '/' at the beggining).

Comment: the route with / prepended doesn't match either.

Comment: According to docs: If your application is not being served from the root url / of your domain, be sure to tell History where the root really is, as an option: Backbone.history.start({pushState: true, root: "/public/search/"}). So, try appending '/' to the root and leave your rules as they were. If that doesn't help, try routing with regex ( this.route(/regex/, function); )

Comment: i appended it: root: '/dashboard/' still doesnt work, and i also tried regex.

Comment: can you paste here one of the regex rules?

Comment: sure, i write a regex only for testing purposes /^edit\/([a-z] )$/ it should match edit/test.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14176/discussion-between-alexandernst-and-cnkt)

Answer (score 0):

is index firing? in general the backbone docs recommend listing your routes from most specific to least specific. It's possible that the other roots aren't being called because `"":"index"` catches everything.

Answer (score 0):

You need a trailing slash in your `Backbone.history.start` call for the `root` argument.

```
var appRouting = new appRouter;
Backbone.history.start({
    pushState: true,
    silent: false,
    root: '/dashboard/'
});
```

You can see this in the [example for `Backbone.history`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#History-start) in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems that the links that call the routes have to be prepended by a "#" character. So if the root of the router is

```
/dashboard/
```

and your route is

```
"questionnaire/info/id/:id": "questionnaireInfo"
```

than the link triggering the route should be for example

```
<a href="/dashboard/#/questionnaire/info/id/1">Load</a>
```

Hope this helps.